# Too many results when eager fetching data by nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to test my test tools with a sample of code below:

```
public void Test_tools()
{
     // Arrange
     DateTime appointmentDate = DateTime.Now;    
     DateTime appointmentDate2 = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
     DateTime appointmentDate3 = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(10);

     string firstName = "Frank";
     string lastName = "Carter";

     DatabaseTools.AddPatientToDatabase(firstName, lastName,
             appointmentDate, appointmentDate2, appointmentDate3);

     var patients = DatabaseTools.GetPatientFromDatabase(firstName, lastName);
}
```

At first I'm adding a **PatientEntity** with 3 **AppointmentEntity** classes to the database (*AddPatientToDatabase* method):

```
public static void AddPatientToDatabase(string firstName, 
         string lastName, params DateTime[] appointmentDate)
{
    PatientEntity patient = new PatientEntity
    {
        FirstName = firstName,
        LastName = lastName
    };

    foreach (DateTime item in appointmentDate)
    {
        var appointment = new AppointmentEntity
        {
            Date = item
        };
        patient.AddAppointment(appointment);
    }

    ISessionFactory sessionForTests =
              NHibernateConfig.CreateSessionFactory(Database.TEST_DB_NAME);

    using (ISession session = sessionForTests.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(patient);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Next I am trying to get the **PatientEntity** from the database using the FirstName and LastName condition using the *GetPatientFromDatabase* method, which looks like this:

```
public static IList<PatientEntity> GetPatientFromDatabase(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    ISessionFactory sessionForTests = 
            NHibernateConfig.CreateSessionFactory(Database.TEST_DB_NAME);

    using (ISession session = sessionForTests.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.QueryOver<PatientEntity>()
                 .Where(k => k.FirstName == firstName && k.LastName == lastName)
                 .Fetch(x => x.Appointments).Eager.List();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I recieve as many **PatientEntity** classes as **AppointmentEntity** classes were addes (instead of only one). In every of 3 results the patient is the same with the same ID and set of appointments. What is my mistake in the Query I have set? I am using PostgreSQL database, where (using pgAdmin) I see, that everying is set properly. The question is, how should I Query to get only one **PatientEntity** with three **AppointmentEntity** classes in his *Appointments* collection.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried to use *CreateCriteria* but once I set eager fetching of the appointment list, I get 3 same patients instead of 1. Is possibly the error inside the eager appointments collection initialization?

```
public static IList<PatientEntity> GetPatientFromDatabase(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    ISessionFactory sessionForTests = NHibernateConfig.CreateSessionFactory(Database.TEST_DB_NAME);
    using (ISession session = sessionForTests.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.CreateCriteria<PatientEntity>()
            .Add(Expression.Eq("FirstName", firstName))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("LastName", lastName))
            .SetFetchMode("Appointments", FetchMode.Eager)
            .List<PatientEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the patient has 3 appointments or you have more than one patient with the same first and last name (or both).

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for reply. I did a clarification of my problem. The database is being dropped before the test, so there is only what is added in the test - one patient with three appointments. My problem is why (when I query by name and surname) I get as many patient results as appointments (the patient is the same in every record).

Comment: Why are you fetching appoinments? .Fetch(x => x.Appointments)

Comment: As far as I understand (and I possibly don't), I do that because I'm closing the session just after the Query. If I don't fetch the data, than I don't have the Appointments list in my Patient. I'm trying to avoid lazy initialization.

Comment: Then test for appointments > 0, don't return every appointment which gives duplicates names.

Comment: But I still don't understand why I get as many patients as appointments when using Fetch. Is it possible to get one patient with all his appointments initialized and not lazy loaded?

Comment: Each row of your database contains firstname, lastname, and appointment.  So you can use either a Distinct() or GroupBy to get unique set of firstname & lastname.  See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @jdweng I was able to come up with another query which allows me to get initialized appointments collection without duplicates in patients list:

```
    public static IList<PatientEntity> GetPatientFromDatabase(string firstName, 
                    string lastName)
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionForTests = 
               NHibernateConfig.CreateSessionFactory(Database.TEST_DB_NAME);

        using (ISession session = sessionForTests.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.QueryOver<PatientEntity>()
                .Where(k => k.FirstName == firstName && k.LastName == lastName)
                .Fetch(x => x.Appointments).Eager
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity).List();
        }
    }
```